# How to build release config with try_compile?

Tags: cmake

I'm not able to build Release config with try_compile. It builds debug only.
`-DCMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION=Release` also doesn't help. I also see that `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` is in use, etc... So, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Variable `CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION` it intended to be set before `try_compile` call. E.g. `set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION Release)`.